# iOS Swift - MPCommandCenter & NowPlayingInfoCenter Controlling Music on Lock Screen

Tags: ios, swift, mpmusicplayercontroller

I am creating a music player (In Swift 3) that uses MPMediaItems and MPMediaPlayerController.  I cannot for the life of me figure out how to control music from the lock screen or notification center...

I have read every article I can find on MPRemoteCommandCenter and MPNowPlayingInfoCenter and I cannot get it to work.

I have enabled background music playback, currently the music continues playing outside of the app, but does not received remote commands.

Below is the code currently being used

In my View Did Load I call the following function

```
let player = MPMusicPlayerController.applicationMusicPlayer()
let commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()

func configureCommandCenter() {
    print("Enter configuration")
    self.commandCenter.playCommand.addTarget { [weak self] event -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus in
        guard let sself = self else { return .commandFailed }
        print("Play")
        sself.player.play()
        self?.getNowPlayingItem()
        return .success
    }

    self.commandCenter.pauseCommand.addTarget { [weak self] event -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus in
        guard let sself = self else { return .commandFailed }
        print("Pause")
        sself.player.pause()
        self?.getNowPlayingItem()
        return .success
    }

    self.commandCenter.nextTrackCommand.addTarget { [weak self] event -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus in
        guard let sself = self else { return .commandFailed }
        print("next")
        sself.player.skipToNextItem()
        self?.getNowPlayingItem()
        return .success
    }

    self.commandCenter.previousTrackCommand.addTarget { [weak self] event -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus in
        guard let sself = self else { return .commandFailed }
        print("Prev")
        sself.player.skipToPreviousItem()
        self?.getNowPlayingItem()
        return .success
    }

}
```

To reiterate my project compiles fine, plays media, continues playing media when app is not in focus and when phone is locked, however no commands are seen from within the app, resulting in the app not being able to be controlled from the lock screen or notification center.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I would also like to mention that I have looked at the Apple API Docs related to both RemoteCommands and InfoCenter.

Am I missing some key step in order to get remote commands registering from within the app?

Comment: Not relevant, but you should delete your `viewDidAppear`. It is not relevant. You're combining the old pre-MPRemoteCommandCenter way with the new MPRemoteCommandCenter way. No point doing that.

Comment: These are the two relevant functions that I am currently using character for character... and they do indeed compile, can you elaborate on why you think they would not? Perhaps that is part of why I am not receiving commands?

Comment: @matt, thank you I will remove the function I was unaware that there was an old and new way this is my first experience with these libraries

Comment: You still have the spaces, and please stop putting those irrelevant JavaScript comments around your code. This is not a runnable JavaScript. — Anyway, I've now answered the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your player is `MPMusicPlayerController.applicationMusicPlayer()`. You cannot use the application music player as a remote control target.

If you want remote control target capabilities, you need your player to be something like an AVAudioPlayer.

Comment: Here is a working project that you can download and run if you want to experiment: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/tree/61f0c753a080040e4a74b912e6c18dd97fe8bcaa/bk2ch14p644remote/ch27p912ducking

Comment: Oh wow thank you, sorry about the javascript mishap, it reformatted my code, it has been fixed.  Am I correct in the fact that while using an AVAudioPlayer will result in the ability to gain remote control target capabilities it then hinders the use of Apple Music (DRM) music?  I am under this assumption because tracks in a users library from Apple Music have no URL and therefore wouldnt be able to be played using an AVAudioPlayer?

Comment: I believe that you are correct, because if you could pass DRM thru your own sound processor you'd be stealing the sound. If you want Apple Music _and_ remote control, then I _think_ you can just use the `systemMusicPlayer` (also known as the Music app). — However, please note that a concern with Apple Music was nowhere in your original question. This really constitutes a completely new question (and feel free to ask it as a new question).

Comment: What about the scenario using MPMusicPlayerController to play Apple Music tracks with the setQueueWithStoreIDs method? How can we use MPRemoteCommandCenter?